# Change the encoding of a file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: character-encoding, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to change the encoding of a file?
For example UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1?

Setting Example Sublime Text:

```json
"default_encoding": "UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 388, accepted):

So here's how to do that:

In the bottom bar of VSCode, you'll see the label `UTF-8`. Click it. A
popup opens. Click `Save with encoding`. You can now pick a new
encoding for that file.

Alternatively, you can change the setting globally in Workspace/User settings using the setting `"files.encoding": "utf8"`. If using the graphical settings page in VSCode, simply search for `encoding`. Do note however that this only applies to newly created files.

Comment: "files.encoding":"utf8" will create files without BOM (which is mostly the better decision). If you want UTF8 files with BOM, the setting is "files.encoding": "utf8bom"

Comment: @Gerfried "If you want UTF8 files with BOM, the setting is `"files.encoding": "utf8bom"`" - it doesn't work. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47089

Comment: please avoid using utf8bom, you not need it

Comment: @sherpya except when (for some annoying program) you do... -.-

Comment: @sherpya I agree. Yet sometimes you do, for example to make the Delphi compiler recognize your UTF-8 files ‍♂️

Comment: VS Code told me my file was encoded in UTF-8, but a program reading that file didn't agree with that assessment. I had to tell VS Code to save it with another encoding first, and save it back to the UTF-8 encoding afterwards for that other program to agree it was UTF-8.

Comment: @sherpya The popular Chocolatey package manager says "PowerShell scripts need to be saved in UTF-8 with BOM. PowerShell ... needs a BOM in order to recognize scripts as UTF-8." https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/create-packages#character-encoding

Answer (score 44):

Apart from the settings explained in the answer by @DarkNeuron:

```js
"files.encoding": "any encoding"
```

you can also specify settings for a specific language like so:

```js
"[language id]": {
  "files.encoding": "any encoding"
}
```

For example, I use this when I need to edit PowerShell files previously created with ISE (which are created in ANSI format):

```js
"[powershell]": {
    "files.encoding": "windows1252"
}
```

You can get a [list of identifiers of well-known languages here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers).

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this setting to change encoding for c files to cp850 (is the best one for Spanish language) but when I create a new file nothing changes, is always setting to utf-8 by default. I tried with different languages and encodings but it still putting the same encode

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers show a possible solution for single files or file types. However, you can define the charset standard in VS Code by following this path:

File > Preferences > Settings > Encoding > Choose your option

This will define a character set as default.
Besides that, you can always change the encoding in the lower right corner of the editor (blue symbol line) for the current project.