# vscode: set encoding for files with a specific extension

Tags: character-encoding, asp-classic, visual-studio-code

I'm working with visual studio code to edit classic asp pages.

In order not to break everything, I need .asp files to be read and written using Windows 1252 encoding.

Is there some way to configure it? if it could be done on a folder/project/workspace basis that would be great.

Comment: Why not just [read the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)? The in-built settings editor even has a search feature, just type "encoding" will be enough to show you examples of defining encoding by file type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [language-specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings).  so something like

```
 "[asp]": {
    "files.encoding": "windows1252"
  },
```

assuming `asp` is your language name, if not, put your language there.

If you want it for only a specific workspace put that into that workspace settings.

Command palette/"Open Workspace Settings"

Comment: Pretty much [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175432/692942) already.

Comment: You are right - although that question started out about changing the encoding for a file, not a language or "an extension". So easy to miss.