# Visual Studio Code can't encode cyrillic characters in output

Tags: unicode, visual-studio-code, output, cp1251

Output in Visual Studio Code can't decode Cyrillic characters:

[image: Visual Studio Code can't decode Cyrillic characters]

The same code works fine in [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm):

[image: The same code works fine in PyCharm]

How do I quickly fix this issue? There must be some simple way.

*Auto Guess Encoding* in *Settings* doesn't work since it's for files, not the output.

Edit: the problem was the Code Runner extension in VSCode. Disabling it or running script in terminal does the job.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3550#issuecomment-343491889?

Comment: Sadly, they didn't really explain how to fix this what seems to be the simplest of issues to have. There must be some sort of checkbox in the settings that I can not find.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3550#issuecomment-341557752?

Comment: Code page 1251 does have the required glyphs to display that string.  But not to display �.  So Python isn't reading the .py file correctly.  Either because the file actually contains � or because Python guessed incorrectly at its encoding.  You can change the .py file encoding to cp1251: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Well, as I said, the same file works fine in PyCharm and the output is displayed correctly there. So for PyCharm encoding any text in this file is not a problem..

Comment: The output shown in the screenshot is from some third-party extension (Code Runner?). You might find further info in the extension's settings or documentation.

Comment: Yes, that's it! The problem was the Code Runner. Apparently it can not process non-latin characters or something..
The code runs smoothly in the terminal, guess I'll have to get used to it now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can configure '[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)' plugin to run your code in the integrated terminal.

Try it:

1. Open VSC Settings: `Ctrl + ,`
2. Search: `code runner run in terminal`
3. [Click on checkbox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzfgl.jpg)

Now your application with Cyrillic symbols run in Integred Terminal without encoding problems.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the Code Runner encoding itself, since the text is displayed correctly in the terminal.

You can add into settings.json :

"code-runner.executorMap": {"python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && py -u"},

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip! Your solution preserves the nice and simple runner output formats. While the 'code runner run in terminal' solves the problem but also loses the output format of runner!