# Words with special characters are not getting rendered properly. Is there a way in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

The special characters are not being rendered correctly, they give the black "?" instead.

I have a string which is coming from API response like "Perrier-**Jouët**" but while displaying on the screen it looks like below

[image]

I am already using `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in my html

can anyone let me know how to get it rendered correctly?

TIA

[ScreenShot of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bdE4.png)

[screenshot while debugging UI after getting the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjePB.png)

Comment: You also have to save your file as UTF-8. Which text editor are you using?

Comment: Do you know that the string is being encoded using function like encodeURI(string)? If so, can you try decoding it using decodeURI(string)?

Comment: @Ry- I am using VS code.

Comment: What does the bottom bar say about the file’s encoding? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code Maybe “Latin-1” or something? (Regardless, you should be able to change it this way.)

Comment: @KomalR I tried decodeURI(string) still it is not getting render. I still has ? in the string.

Comment: @Ry- encoding tech is selected as utf-8.

Comment: @VaibhavJain: Sorry, I missed that it was coming from an API response. We actually need to see your code, then. It’s also possible the API is just returning a bad response – you should check whether that’s the case, maybe by requesting it manually or through another tool that uses the same API.

Comment: @Ry- attached response screenshot to the original question. also attached the screenshot while debugging when i get response in the UI code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe convert them to HTML Entities might help you.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp

And use character-set as UTF-8.