# VS Code can't read unicode language written in other editors

Tags: utf-8, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use VS Code but I'm having a problem opening code written with other editors, VS Code can't read korean language unicode? utf-8? what we call other languages in code?

I wrote the code with vim editor with some comment written in korean, and any other editors can read korean languagee but VS Code like following.

```
ret.insert(ret.end(), bottom.begin(), bottom.end()); // written in vim
// 는 다음과 같음


ret.insert(ret.end(), bottom.begin(), bottom.end()); // opened in VS Code
// �� ������ ����
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There is just one Unicode (with various versions/enhancement). But not all fonts support all Unicode characters/languages, and in Windows, UTF-8 is not yet the default encoding, so you may need to tell VSCode that your files are UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your VSCode is opening the file with UTF8 encoding.

[Change the encoding of a file in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code)