# error while compiling my sass code, how should i proceed from here on?

Tags: css, sass

This is the code I am pasting down below, when I am trying to compile this using sass compiler, I'm getting an error which states:-

```
"Error: Invalid CSS after "�": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "��$"
        on line 1 of sass/c:\Users\shain\Desktop\udemy assignments and other stuffs\advanced css and sass\starter- NAtours\sass\main.scss
>> ��$
   ^
"
```

I tried using the command line(power shell to compile and live compile sass extension in vs code both aren't working for me.

1. https://codepen.io/poopykun/pen/PowrrGO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900"    rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">

        <title>Natours | Exhilarating tours for venturesome humans</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
                <div class="header__logo-box">
                    <img src="../starter- NAtours/img/logo-white.png" alt="logo" class="header__logo" >
                </div>

                    <div class="header__text-box">
                    <h1 class="heading-primary">
                        <span class="heading-primary--main">NATURE</span>
                        <span class="heading-primary--sub">is where life happens</span>
                    </h1>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn--white btn--animated">Discover the tours </a>
                    </div>

        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:-

```
$color-primary-light: #e75d8b; 
$color-primary-dark: #8a1d52; 


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%; 
}

body{

        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        /*font-size: 1.6rem ; */
        line-height: 1.7;
        color: #777;
        padding: 3rem;

}


.header {

    height: 95vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right bottom,
        rgba($color-primary-light, 0.8),
        rgba($color-primary-dark, 0.8)) , 
        url(../myimg/nature.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    position: relative;

    clip-path: polygon(0% 80vh, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 99%);

}

.header__logo-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
    left: 4rem;
}

.header__logo {
    height: 3.5rem;
}

.header__text-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;

}

.heading-primary {
    color: beige;
text-transform: uppercase;
backface-visibility: hidden;
margin-bottom: 6rem;

}

.heading-primary--main {
    display: block;
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3.5rem;

    animation-name: moveInLeft;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;

}

.heading-primary--sub
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1.75rem;
    animation-name: moveInRight;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;

}

/* to animate the stuff (its amazing!) */

@keyframes moveInLeft{

    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-10rem);
    }

    80%{
        transform: translateX(1rem);

        }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0);
    }
}




    @keyframes moveInRight{

        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(10rem);
        }

        80% {
            transform: translateX(-1rem);    
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate(0);
        }
    }

    @keyframes moveInBottom{

        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(3rem);
        }


        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate(0);
        }
    }

.btn:link, .btn:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10rem;
    transition: all .2s;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.6rem;


}

.btn:hover{
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.btn:active{
    transform: translateY(-1px);
    box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

}

.btn--white {
    background-color: beige;
    color: #777;
}

.btn::after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.btn--white::after{
    background-color: beige;
}

.btn:hover::after{
    transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
    opacity: 0;
}

.btn--animated
{
    animation: moveInBottom .5s ease-out .75s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
```

2. posting an image :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/n95kH.jpg

Comment: What is the command you are running to try and compile your sass?

Comment: You copy pasted scss contents from somewhere which contains illegal characters. That's my rough first guess. Try to write it on your own and see if it helps..

Comment: @dpDesignz npm run compile:sass

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i actually im writing it on my own sir, its just the course im taking doing the project from the same course, so have written everything from scratch

Comment: So you have a command in your npm packages file called `compile:sass`? What does that line contain?

Comment: Also, check in the image you posted. The error message should explain what's going wrong. Looks like your file has been saved in a UTF-16 format. Make sure it's saved as a UTF-8 file and see what that does.

Comment: Encoding mismatch? Are you sure all the files have the same charset?

Comment: @dpDesignz {
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "landing page for me",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css"
  },
  "author": "Shain",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
  }
}

Comment: So you sure about that? You haven't copy-pasted a single line from the course? What will happen when you remove complete contents from the error-throwing scss file and run it? Still it throws error?

Comment: @MrLister i actually dont have a clue about charset at all, i will try to learn about it right now

Comment: What editor/IDE are you using?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes written it myself, when i use the normal css instead of going to the sass way and converting it, it just works very fine

Comment: I agree with @MrLister.. That's could possibly be an encoding issue. If you can replicate it in `stackblitz` that would be helpful.

Comment: @dpDesignz im using visual studio code and added these extensions to it to compile my sass ie:
1. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass

Comment: Ok, you need to check the encoding of your files. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @dpDesignz okay did check the encoding you guys are amazing!

Comment: @dpDesignz sorry for spamming but thanks a lottttttttttt!!!!

Comment: No worries. Please mark my answer as correct. Best of luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the encoding of your files. Check in the image you posted. The error message should explain what's going wrong. Looks like your file has been saved in a UTF-16 format. Make sure it's saved as a UTF-8 file and see what that does.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40365121/1248664 on changing your encoding in VS Code

Comment: THANKSSSSSSSS :DDDDDDD