# How I can view greek letters in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode for c++ coding.

I want my code to show Greek letters.

For example,

```
int alpha = 0; => int α = 0;
int delta[n][n]; => int δ[n][n];
but, int Delta = x => int Δ[n][n];
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the `VS Code` extension [**Greek Alphabet Snippets**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lucas-rezende.greek-alphabet-snippets)

There, you can just write `alpha + Tab`, and it will convert it to α.

Comment: Instead of providing the answer directly, try writing a comment explaining the solution if it's not too lengthy. @Tim

Answer (score 0):

On Mac

⟶ System preferences
⟶ Keyboard
⟶ Input Sources Tab
⟶ `+` at bottom left
⟶ add and select `Unicode Hex Input` from panel on right

* Then  enter unicode characters via  `alt`+`[code]` eg `27f6`

On Windows, skip all the steps with arrows, and just do the step with the star.

Get codes from https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html or Wikipedia

Comment: Did not work for me.  I'm on a Mac OS 11.6, was able to do the steps with the arrows, but `Option` (the Mac equivalent of `alt`) + `[code]` did not create the correct result.   E.g. `Option` + `27f6` yields ™¶ƒ§.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already an answer here: [Change the encoding of a file in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code/40365121#40365121)

What worked for me was:

1. Change the input language of OS in ΕΛ
2. Then Click the Encoding format at the right lower corner of VS Code editor and selecting from the dropdown list the option 'Save with encoding' and then selecting the option 'UTF-8'

After this I was able to write greek letters to the editor as well as copy greek text from other txt file.

I hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score -1):

The better way is to add `Unicode Latex extension` in **VS-Code**.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oijaz.unicode-latex

Once the extension is added use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type:

`>Unicode: Insert Math symbol`

then type the *latex format.*