# Vscode chinese words encode issue

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

file open in vscode:
[vscode showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIOJU.png)

```
        <BillCard
          title={"åŒ»ç–—åˆ†æœŸ"}
          status={item.applyStatus}
```

file open in sublime Text
[sublime text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVdqW.png)

```
<Wrapper key={index}>
        <BillCard
          title={"医疗分期"}
          status={item.applyStatus}
```

already setted `"files.autoGuessEncoding": true,` in setttings.json  of vscode.

and it is *.jsx file

not sure why it would happen

Comment: In 2020 I would not guess unless I have a reason to. Just set the default encoding (or at least the project encoding) to UTF-8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the encoding of a file in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your file encoding is set to `UTF-8`.

In VSCode you can open that file and press <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl/⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then search `change file encoding` and select `UTF-8`.