# nodejs encoding (Visual Studio)

Tags: node.js, encoding

When I use any characters from utf-8 encoding, I see the following ������
both in console and browser:

```
console.log("привет");
res.send("привет");
```

I noticed this for every new  nodejs project in Visual Studio.
I opened one of my old projects, it works fine there. Can't track the root cause

Comment: Please check your file encoding, when you save file you save the file as ASCII or UTF-8, may be your file saved as UTF-8

Comment: Thank you! Correct, wrong encoding of file.  Actually issue with Visual Studio it saved file in wrong encoding, and when select Save As and select encoding it just return some error. Please post it as answer, I will confirm resolved

Comment: Here the step to change it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code#answer-40365121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes if you save a file there will be an option to choose encoding as ASCII or UTF-8

your file might got saved to accept Unicode's so if you save your file as ASCII this issue will be resolved