# VSCODE how to reopen or save file with ASCII encoding

Tags: visual-studio-code, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have text file that contains an SQL that queries a phrase in hebrew.

I wrote the SQL in VSCODE using utf-8 encoding.

Now i have to run this sql using a teradata utility called bteq.
this utility uses ascii encoding.

I tried to reopen or save the file in VSCODE with new encoding but couldn't find an ascii encoding.

In ultra-edit editor there is an ascii encoding and when i copy paste the sql to ultra-edit and save it with ascii encoding the sql runs successfully.

Is there any way to use VSCODE to save the file in ascii encoding?

**Update: 2022-05-23**

Following the comments:

The reason i need this is that i work with a teradata database.

The tool with which which the SQL is written is called "Teradata Assistant".

Teradata assistant version is: 16.20.0.9 2019-10-25

Database version is: 16.20.53.48

With this tool i can write the sql with hebrew letters and save it as a text file.

When i open the file with teradata assistant the file is displayed correctly with the hebrew letters.

However when i open the same file with VSCODE using UTF-8 all the hebrew letters are replaced with this symbol:  �

Finally when i open the file with notepad with ANSI encoding the file is opened with the hebrew letters displayed correctly.

I find it odd that VSCODE can't do something that notepad can do..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Check this link @Rafael

Comment: Thanks. i stumbled across that link in my preliminary search. However there is no ASCII encoding among the options in the "select file encoding" dropdown in VSCODE. I understand that ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, and i need that or an equivalent encoding that the utility can read.

Comment: It looks like you can't really enforce ASCII using Visual Studio Code. UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, it should work for you as long as you don't type non-ASCII characters.

Comment: with ultra edit how does it encode hebrew characters in an ASCII encoding, have you used a hex editor to view the result

Comment: I totally missed the Hebrew bit... It's physically impossible to store Hebrew in ASCII. It's hard to believe that a data tool doesn't support UTF-8 in 2022. Is it possible that's failing because you're feeding it with [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) rather than valid UTF-8?

Comment: I have added more details to the problem description.

Comment: BTEQ just defaults to ASCII, but you can change it, of course. `bteq -c UTF8` should be what you want. See [Encoding Controls for Unicode Sessions](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Basic-Teradata-Query-Reference/February-2022/Starting-and-Exiting-BTEQ/Starting-a-BTEQ-Session/Encoding-Controls-for-Unicode-Sessions)

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth -  i tried: `bteq -c UTF8 < mybteq.sql > log.txt` but log.txt shows that 0 rows were returned. But when i copy&paste the same query from VSCODE to teradata assistant, correct results are displayed.

Comment: To those who say "Use UTF-8" and "Hard to believe something not supporting UTF-8" I  can only say you need to learn a little bit more about what software is out there. Not everyone is using the bleeding edge tech and some things just require ASCII and there is nothing you can do about that.