# Agda: Getting question mark symbols after compiling file

Tags: agda, agda-mode

I installed Agda and Im using VSC to load files, but I have an error when I try to load a saved file. The file open and displays correctly, but when I load it seems that some unicode characters conver to "?". Before loading file:

[image]

After loading file:

[image]

Comment: See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code except select "Reopen with encoding" instead of save

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the encoding of a file in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082741/change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: No, that didn't work, I was using UTF-8 already, and I'm still seeing the same ?? symbols after reloading with UTF-8 (which has always been the default option).

Comment: Interestingly, when I open the text file in Notepad++, it displays correctly. So it looks like a bug in visual studio code?

Comment: I can bet you $10 right now that notepad detects another encoding. You’re very quick jumping to conclusion it’s a bug in extremely popular software. It almost never is.