# invalid identifier while using a custom operator

Tags: julia

I need to make a custom function that returns 0 on x ^ 0, so i made the following:

```
function custom_pow(base, exponent)
    if exponent == 0
        return 0
    else
        return base^exponent
    end
end


⟑(base, exponent) = custom_pow(base, exponent)
```

it works as expected on REPL:
[REPL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JJtq.png)

however, if try to debug the code using it i get the following:
[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ez24.png)

also, if i close and open the file again, the custom operator ⟑ (\wedgedot) is changed to ?

Anyway to make it work? Also i'm using VS Code

Comment: It sounds like you're saving the file with inappropriate character encoding. Set it to something sensible like UTF-8. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40365121/13963086#

Comment: @k314159 I think it would be great if you made that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @k314159 commented, reopening with UTF-8 solved the issue as i was using windows-1252