# AutoHotkey hotkeys does not work in Firefox

Tags: autohotkey

I make [hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) in AutoHotkey, code of my script:

```
#sc01A::send «
#sc01B::send »
#sc048::send —
#sc03C::send @
```

#### Scancode — key in English keyboard layout:

```
sc01A — [
sc01B — ]
sc048 — Numpad8
sc03C — F2
```

How to work my script: when I press <kbd>Super+[</kbd>, insert symbol `«`  and so on.

[image: Script in Sublime]

I saved my script in encoding `UTF-8 with BOM` and I run my script as administrator.

This script worked in:

- Sublime Text 3
- Google Chrome
- CMD.exe

But in any Firefox input and textarea forms this script not worked besides last line:

[image: Script in Firefox]

I tested on newest Firefox version without plugins. What should I do to all my keyboard shortcuts works in Firefox?

#### Environments

- Windows 1067
- Firefox 48.0.2

Thanks.

Comment: 1. [Using AutoHotKey to enter the unicode symbols on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/a/654152) 2. [How do I use Unicode in AutoHotKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15635635) 3. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/87602-autohotkey-stopped-working-for-firefox-only/  So in your case it's `send {U+00AB}` and `send {U+00BB}`

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you very much! Please, move your comment in answer, so I can up to you reputation.